# rsync failing with curly braces expansion

Tags: bash, rsync, curly-braces

I am trying to run the following rsync command:

```
$ rsync -avz --delete . myuser@myhost:/projects/build{08..40}/

Unexpected remote arg: myuser@myhost/projects/build08/
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1201) [sender=3.0.6]
```

I do not understand why the command above fails. If I replace `build{08..40}` with `build08`, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expansion of curly braces results in multiple remote locations being passed to rsync.

```
rsync -avz --delete . user@host:/dir{1..3}/
```

becomes

```
rsync -avz --delete . user@host:/dir1/ user@host:/dir2/ user@host:/dir3/
```

which produces the error you are seeing.

Comment: I thought rsync would rsync to all remote locations in that case. Using a loop with 'for' and 'seq' instead worked. Thanks!